# Is a table (from source system) that contains only relationships and current status of a row from another table a fact table in Data Warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact-table, bottom-up

I am developing a BI system for our company, from scratch, and currently, I am designing a data warehouse. I am completely new to this so there are many things that I don't really understand, so I need to hear some more insights into this.

My problems are:

1) In our source system, there are tables called "Booking" and "BookingAccess". Booking table holds the data of a booking, such as check-in time and check-out time, booking date, booking number, gross amount of that booking.

Whereas in BookingAccess, it holds foreign keys related to the booking, such as bookerID, customerID, processID, hotelID, paymentproviderID and a current status of that booking. Booking and BookingAccess has a 1:1 relation ship.

Our source system is about checking the validity of those bookings, these bookings are not ours. We receive these booking information from other sources, outsource the above process for them. The gross amount is just an information of that booking that we need to validate, their are not parts of our business. The current status of a booking which is hold in the BookingAccess table is the current status of that booking in our system, which can be "Processing" or "Finshed".

From what I read from Ralph Kimball, in this situation, the "Booking" is the Dimension table, and the BookingAccess should be the fact. I feel that the BookingAccess is some what a [Accumulating Snapshot table], in which I should track the time when a booking is "Processing", and when a booking is "Finshed".

Do I get it right?

---

2) In "Booking" table, there is also a foreign key called "ImportID". This key links to a table called "Import". This "Import" table hold history records of files (these file contain bookings which will be written to the "Booking" table) which were imported to our system, including attributes such as file name, imported date, total booking imported...

From my point of view, this is clearly a fact table.

But the problem is that, the "Import" table and the "Booking" table has a relationship of one to many (1 ImportID in "Import" table can have 1, 2 or more records which have a same ImportID in "Booking" table). This is against the idea of fact tables which insists that the relationship between Fact and Dimension must be many-to-one, which fact is always in the many side.

So what approach should I use to solve this case? I'm thinking of using bridge tables to solve this problem. But I don't know if this is a good practice, as there are a lot of record in the "Import" table, so I will have to create a big bridge table just to covers all of this.

---

3) Should I separate a table (from source system) which contains a mix of relationships and information to a fact table containing only relationships, and dimension table containing only information? (For example, a table called "Customer" in source system. This table contains some things like customer name, customer address and customertype id, customer parentID....)

I am asking this because I feel that if I use BI tools to analyze things (for example, analyzing the number of customers which has customertypeid = 1), I feel it's some what weird if there are no fact tables involved in.

Or should I treat it as a mere dimension table and use snowflake-schema? But this will lead to a mix of Star-Schema and snowflake-schema in our Data Warehouse. Is this normal? I have read some official sources (most likely Oracle) stating that one should try to avoid using and mixing snowflake-schema as much as possible. But some sources like Microsoft say that this is very normal. Even the Advanture Work Data Warehouse sample database uses this kind of approach.

Or should I de-normalize every relation in that "Customer" table? But I don't think this is a good approach as it will make the Customer contain a lot of columns, and it will be very hard to track the history of every row in the "DIM_Customer" table. For example, if any change occur in any relation of "Customer" table, the whole "DIM_Customer" table will need to be updated.

---

I still have a lot of question regarding to Data Warehouse. I am working with it nearly alone, without any help or consultant. So pardon me if I made any kind of inconveniences or mistakes.

Comment: For your first problem may I know why do you consider booking access as fact table and booking as a dimension? if you are implementing start schema dimension to fact relationships are always will be one to many.

Comment: Because [BookingAccess] hold the current status of booking in our system, such as "Received", "In Queue", "Processing", "Finshed", and also relation key that links to another table, such as CustomerKey, ProcessTypeKey. I think this looks very likely to be a [Accumulating Snapshot fact table], which will store milestones such as when this booking was "Received" or "Finished".

Of course, I know that in star-schema, the relation between Dimension and Factable should be 1 to many which many side is always the fact table. But in what I've perceived so far, "many" here can be "1 or more".

Comment: So, what would you recomend me here? Should I de-normalize altogether these [Booking] and [Booking Access] tables to only one table and treat this as a fact table? 

Or should I treat them all as Dimension tables? If so, this may become a factless datamart which contains only dimension table? Is this normal? 

Or should I treat them all as Fact tables?

Comment: In my opinion, you should de-normalize altogether and treat as a fact table.so you have the fact table which is connected to other dimensions. (customer, ProccessType etc).

Comment: I've just come up with a term called "degenerate dimension", and looks like your solution is exactly like this, de-normalizing altogether the BookingAccess into a new fact table,  treating all of things that comes from the [Booking] table like BookingID, BookingAccessID, BookingNo, check-in, check-out date.. as degenerate dimension.

What makes me feel worried about this approach is, this may make the new fact table very long, due to that it's joined from the 2 tables. Is this normal? On top of that, is it legit to make a relationship between 2 fact tables through these degenerate dimension?

Comment: Also, can I use these degenerate dimensions to perform the "Drill Across" technique? "Drill Across" technique requires to have a "conformed dimensions" to perform, which I understands is: when performing, the 2 fact table must share a same set of column. But can these "degenerate dimension" treated as "conformed dimensions"? In paper, I think this is legit, but I don't really sure if this is a best practice, as in my opinion, I feel this is somewhat like connecting directly from a fact to a fact table, and this seems a bit weird.

Comment: It's okay to have a long fact table because fact tables are holding the data which is growing pretty frequently. since the relationship between two tables is one-to-one I don't think there will be a large growth.

Comment: you can't connect a fact table with a fact table. you can have two fact table which is sharing the same dimension table. if you are thinking about connecting two fact tables, why can't you think about having one fact table instead of two? I think you will be adding an extra measure to the fact table you already have.

Comment: and yes, it's like de-generating dimension kind of thing I'm suggesting.

Comment: Yes I know that it's not allowed to join 2 fact tables directly. But here we have degenarate dimension (BookingAccessID, BookingNo...) in the de-normalized Booking fact table. For example, I want to join Booking factable and the Booking_Note fact table, which share the same BookingAccessID. At first glance, it looks very like that I'm connecting directly from a fact table to a fact table, but in fact, it's not. Because BookingAccessID itself is a (degenerate) dimension, so that means actually, the two fact table are connected by a dimension. So it's completely legit.
Is my statement correct?

Comment: The booking_note table is a table that hold every note of bookings, which is generated when my company staffs want to take some notes related to a booking. Eg: "This booking has some problem and needs to be delegated to higher position", "this booking is weird"....